# Dynamically add layout components (combine xml and manual layout)

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any way to combine xml-based layout and "manual" layout? F.ex.:

I use the "standard" xml layout like this:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.mainscreen);
```

And then I want to have some more dynamic contents, adding it like this:

```
 LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
 setContentView(layout);
 layout.addView(new CreateItemButton(this, "Button", 1));
```

I realize of cours that I cannot create a new layout like in the line above, but I'd probably have to initialize the xml layout in some way. But - is it possible, or do I just have to go with a 100% manual layout if I want to dynamically add components? Or is there perhaps another, more elegant/correct way of doing it?

(What I want to do is create buttons based on entries fetched from a database. These will wary in number and text/contents, hence the attempt to add them dynamically instead of in the xml layout file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add any element dynamically to your xml layout.
You have to have a container in your xml layout where you are going to add your dynamic elements. Say empty LinearLayout with id="container". Also you can build everything dynamically and setContentView(yourView); Where is yourView is a root layout element with other child elements added.

EX:

```
Button myButton = new Button(this);
myButton.setLayoutParams(params);
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
container.addView(myButton);
```

or

```
LinearLayout myLayout = new LinearLayout(this);  
...
container.addView(myLayout);
```

Comment: Thanks, Maxim - that worked. Not sure why I didn't get it to work before, but now I'm able to both add "static" contents in the xml file AND add dynamic contents directly in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will helpful to you.

Try this Code...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   

       RelativeLayout rl= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
       Button b2=new Button(this);
       b2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
       b2.setText("Dynamic");
       b2.setTextSize(30);
       b2.setTextColor(b1.getTextColors());
       rl.addView(b2);
    }
}
```